# Как заставить класс узнать про экземпляр другого класса?

Tags: c++

У меня есть класс `BinTree`, описывающий бинарное дерево поиска:

```
 class BinTree
    {
    public:
        BinTree();

        ~BinTree();

        bool IsEmpty();
        bool IsFull();
        const int Size() const;

        bool Add(Item data);
        bool In(Item data);
        bool Delete(Item data);
        void Traverse();
...
}
```

Для класса BinTree, у меня в int main() создан его экземпляр:

```
#include<iostream>
#include"BinTree.h"
#include"menu.h"
//extern BinTree mytree;
int main()
{
    BinTree mytree;//экземпляр
    return 0;
}
```

Мне нужно,чтобы этот экземпляр был доступен и в другом классе- `menu`

```
class menu
{
private:

    static void upp(string str);
public:

    static void addpet();
};
void menu::upp(string str)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
    {
        str[i] = toupper(str[i]);
    }
}
void menu::addpet()
{
    Item temp;
    cout << "Please enter name of pet: " << endl;
    //std:sin >> temp.Name;
    getline(std::cin, temp.Name);
    cout << "Please enter pet kind: " << endl;
    getline(std::cin, temp.Kind);
    upp(temp.Name);
    upp(temp.Kind);
    mytree.Add(temp);

}
```

Проблема возникает в этой строчке

```
mytree.Add(temp);
```

Потому что "идентификатор mytree не определен". Как тогда сделать так, чтобы класс menu узнал про экземпляр другого класса? Единственное,что мне в голову пришло - сделать глобальную область видимости между файлами с помощью `extern`(но это на крайний случай). Есть ли более правильные способы,то есть без использования глобальной переменной?

Comment: так создайте этот обьект  mytree  в  функции  menu::addpet. В чем проблема?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А если так?

```
#include<iostream>
#include"BinTree.h"
#include"menu.h"

int main()
{
    BinTree mytree;//экземпляр

    menu::addpet(mytree); // <- сплавляем дерево по ссылке

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void menu::addpet(BinTree& mytree)
{
    ...
    mytree.Add(temp);
}
```